# Install ligthdm after autoremove lightdm

Tags: uninstall, lightdm

I think I did a big mistake and `autoremove` through 
    sudo apt-get autoremove lightdm

instead of `remove lightdm`. So in my little knowledge about Linux I think I removed more than `lightdm`.

I can't fix it through `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. Or do I have to install the whole OS? 
The reason for the `autoremove` was that the login was in loop and after login the login window appeared again.

I need some help **:)**

Answer (score 0):

You might try: `sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`
assuming you are using gnome, or mate. 
You could try  `sudo apt-get install lightdm-kde-greeter`
if you are using kde. 
if you are using unity, then try installing unity-greeter:
`sudo apt-get install unity-greeter`

if the appropriate version of any one of those is installed, but you still cannot login via the greeter, then shift to a terminal, (ctrl+alt+F6) and login via the terminal. Once you are logged in there, you might try giving the `sudo lightdm` command, and see what happens. If it works, or fails with errors. You might also try `startx` to see if your DE loads properly after you login via the terminal.

Comment: For sudo lightdm i get the fail: "failed to use bus name org.free desktop.DisplayManager, do you have appropriate permissions?". And for startx: I get the error:"errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the x server".

Comment: But with sudo service lightdm stop and start and sudo startx there are no fails or errors. But switching to DE with Ctrl+Alt+F7 there is a black screen.